# How to format text inside CSS content Property

Tags: html, css

I want to format the text inside the content property. I don't seem to find way to style it since content only takes a string(and others) but not HTML directly. See Slider below
[image: slider]

I want the "Agency Management" text to be bold (and specify a font for it as well) then the remaining text below it like in this design:
[image: slider design].

I am using the content property like this:
`

```css
.btn-color-mode-switch > label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner:before{
    content: 'Agency Management For agencies working on behalf of retail clients';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    top: 7px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

`

I need the Agency Management text to be bold and size 8px. Then the remaining text on a new line. I have tried to use the attr() function like this:
`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color_mode" id="color_mode" value="1">
<label for="color_mode" merchant="Agency Management" merchant-description="For agencies working on behalf of retail clients" class="btn-color-mode-switch-inner"></label>

.btn-color-mode-switch > label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner:before{
    content: attr(merchant) '/' attr(merchant-description);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    top: 7px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

`
However, I can't find any way to break the text. I would appreciate any help. For more info, you can check out [this](https://codepen.io/vesta-nassone/pen/poKKMwN) codepen.

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

body{
    display: table;
}

/*switch styles*/

div.btn-container{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}


label {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #424242;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch > label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: block;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch > label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner:before{
    content: 'Agency Management For agencies working on behalf of retail clients';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    top: 7px;
    right: 5px;

}

.btn-color-mode-switch > label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner:after{
    content: "Business Management. For Single Merchants running 1+ stores";
    width: 150px;
/*     height: 100%; */
    background:  #464C42;
  color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px -2px #111;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch > .alert{
    display: none;
    background: #FF9800;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch input[type="checkbox"]{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0px;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner{
    background: #E0E0E0;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner:after{
    content: "Agency Management For agencies working on behalf of retail clients";
    left: 100px;
    background: #469DA3;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner:before{
    content: 'Business Management. For Single Merchants running 1+ stores';
    right: auto;
    left: 20px;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label.btn-color-mode-switch-inner{
    /*background: #66BB6A; */
    /*color: #fff;*/
}

.btn-color-mode-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .alert{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <label class="switch btn-color-mode-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" name="color_mode" id="color_mode" value="1">
      <label for="color_mode" data-on="Dark" data-off="Light" class="btn-color-mode-switch-inner"></label>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use `\a` in combination with `white-space: pre` to create a line break. I'm not aware of any way to style parts of the content different than other parts.

Comment: Yes that seem to create the line break thanks. Now I just need to style the text individually, currently it's styling the entire string :-)

Comment: I believe it's currently not possible to that. In theory if you were able to chain `::before::first-line` you would get pretty close. But, unfortunately, that's doesn't work. Why don't you add `<span>`s?

Comment: I'm not too sure how I would go about using <span>s, because I have a single checkbox, and I want the text on that checkbox to change, hence I thought content was the best option. I have however chained the attr() and gave the input multiple attributes then styling each individual attribute, but somehow its using the last applied style to all. See below: 


<label merchant="Business Management" merchant-description="For Single Merchants running 1+ stores" agency="Agency Management" agency-description="For agencies working on behalf of retail clients"/>

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with CSS content? Add the content to the HTML. It will be more accessible and easier to style.

Comment: It really makes zero sense to do it this way. If you have content that is an integral part of your page, it should be part of the HTML. If it is just a decoration/style, then use a style sheet. You have the accessibility concerns as raised by Sean as well as SEO implications. Then there is the practicality that you are limited to what you can do with it.

Comment: I'd also be using radio buttons instead of a checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you can create a line break in the content using `\a` and applying `white-space: pre`. However, it is currently not possible to apply different styles to different parts of the content from the `content` property, even if it's a concatenation of 2 attributes.

So, in order to achieve the desired style you need to add elements to the HTML. In the snippet below I placed the input immediately before the label and added 2 `<span>`s inside the label.

I still utilized pseudo elements for the teal background as well as for the larger texts.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/*switch styles*/

input#color_mode {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

label.btn-color-mode-switch {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #424242;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch::before {
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #469DA3;
}

input#color_mode:checked+.btn-color-mode-switch::before {
  left: 50%;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch>span {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch>span.business {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch>span::before {
  content: 'Agency Management';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn-color-mode-switch>span.business::before {
  content: "Business Management";
}

input#color_mode:checked+.btn-color-mode-switch>span.business {
  color: #424242;
}

input#color_mode:checked+.btn-color-mode-switch>span.agency {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="color_mode" id="color_mode" value="1">
  <label class="switch btn-color-mode-switch" for="color_mode" data-on="Dark" data-off="Light">
      <span class="business">For Single Merchants running 1+ stores</span>
      <span class="agency">For agencies working on behalf of retail clients</span>
    </label>
</div>
```